# Column invalid in the select list, not contaned in aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would like to display columns like this:

```
ProductID | Price | PricingPlanLicense | PricingPlanQuality
----------+-------+--------------------+-------------------    
1            16.99         Buy                 HD
1            12.99         Buy                 SD
1             2.99         Rent                HD
3             4.99         Rent                HD
```

The problem is that in my data I have multiple `PricingPlanLicense` and `PricingPlanQuality` combinations and I would like to take the one with the highest price.

So far I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    ProductID, MAX(Price), PricingPlanLicense, PricingPlanQuality
FROM 
    [#ExportPricingTable] 
GROUP BY 
    PricingPlanLicense, PricingPlanQuality
```

But this doesn't work because `ProductID` is not aggregated, how can I tell SQL Server to use the `ProductID` that is already there?

Thanks

Comment: You can't, not easily anyway. When you use aggregation every attribute you `select` has to be either in an aggregate function or in the `group by`. Anything else wouldn't make sense if you think about it.

Comment: Why aren't you grouping by ProductID too? Seems that is what you want.

Comment: Michael that did it, simpler than expected, maybe you should put that in an answer.

Comment: just made the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ProductID` to the `Group By` clause.

```
SELECT ProductID, MAX(Price), PricingPlanLicense, PricingPlanQuality
FROM [#ExportPricingTable] 
GROUP BY ProductID, PricingPlanLicense, PricingPlanQuality
```

Answer (score 1):

A canonical way of doing this to use a join to obtain the `ProductID` corresponding to each group which has the maximum price:

```
SELECT t1.ProductID, t1.Price, t1.PricingPlanLicense, t1.PricingPlanQuality
FROM [#ExportPricingTable] t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(Price) AS maxPrice, PricingPlanLicense, PricingPlanQuality
    FROM [#ExportPricingTable] 
    GROUP BY PricingPlanLicense, PricingPlanQuality
) t2
    ON t1.Price = t2.maxPrice AND t1.PricingPlanLicense = t2.PricingPlanLicense AND
       t1.PricingPlanQuality = t2.PricingPlanQuality
```

Here is a demo you can try:

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can pick one ID, using either `MIN` or `MAX`, like:

```
SELECT MIN(ProductID), MAX(Price), PricingPlanLicense, PricingPlanQuality
FROM [#ExportPricingTable] 
GROUP BY PricingPlanLicense, PricingPlanQuality
```

This will select the minimum `ProductID` value for every `PricingPlanLicense, PricingPlanQuality` group of values.

Comment: Using MIN for productID collapses all products, I get only 4 rows with the same ProductID

Comment: @FailedUnitTest The only thing that collapses rows is the `GROUP BY` clause. What do you get if you simply omit `MIN(ProductID)` from the query?

Comment: I get 4 rows with no ProductID

Answer (score 0):

When you want to select more columns than your group for an aggregate, you can use row_number() to order the data then select first row:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ProductID, Price, PricingPlanLicense, PricingPlanQuality
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by PricingPlanLicense, PricingPlanQuality ORDER BY Price desc) RN
  FROM [#ExportPricingTable] 
)
WHERE RN = 1
```